# How to increase the accuracy of the nodejs-multilabel SVM classifier?

Tags: node.js, classification, svm

This is our code. Classifier is consistently misclassifying. We need to classify numerical data. Please let us know how can we increase its accuracy or if we are missing on something.

```
var multilabel = require('multilabelsvm');
var actionClassifier = new multilabel.Classifier({kernel:'linear'});
var jsonObject=new Object();
var jsonObject = require("/home/Desktop/Final/data.json");
var trainSet=[];

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
trainSet[i] = { input:jsonObject.users[i].cap_dim1,output:jsonObject.users[i].username };
}
console.log(trainSet);


actionClassifier.trainBatch(trainSet);


var json = actionClassifier.toJSON()
var newActionClassifier = new multilabel.Classifier();

console.log('----------SVM Classifier----');
//importing 
newActionClassifier.fromJSON(json);

console.log(newActionClassifier.classify(captchadim));
```